# How to save resorted rows by reordering array & saving to database? (jQuery sortable | Wordpress | PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using jQuery `.sortable` to reorder rows in a table in a plug-in's admin dashboard in a Wordpress environment.

Each row shows saved data in the database, and their order is based on how the array in the database is saved. Each item is appended onto the current array list of items for every new addition (e.g. latest one added will be the last one on the list), and currently there is no way of re-ordering the items.

Example of array content:

```
a: 4: {
    s: 4: "id-0";
    a: 2: {
        s: 5: "first";
        s: 4: "girl";
        s: 6: "second";
        s: 5: "woman";
    }
    s: 4: "id-1";
    a: 2: {
        s: 5: "first";
        s: 3: "boy";
        s: 6: "second";
        s: 3: "man";
    }
    s: 4: "id-2";
    a: 2: {
        s: 5: "first";
        s: 4: "frog";
        s: 6: "second";
        s: 6: "prince";
    }
    s: 4: "id-3";
    a: 2: {
        s: 5: "first";
        s: 2: "hi";
        s: 6: "second";
        s: 5: "hello";
    }
}
```

Based on the above array, my table rows will be showing:

```
<TABLE>

ROW 1 - first: girl | second: woman
ROW 2 - first: boy | second: man
ROW 3 - first: frog | second: prince
ROW 4 - first: hi | second: hello

</TABLE>
```

Now I have recently implemented [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to my rows, allowing them to be resorted using a drag & drop behaviour.

My question is: **How do I reorder the array items the same way as the current order of resorted rows? How would you do it?**

Answer (score 2):

You can add data to the table rows. So when creating the table, you would add a attribute to each row:

```
<tr data-source-id="id-0">
```

When submitting the form, you can get all data attributes:

```
var order = [];
jQuery.find('tr').each(function() {
  order.push(jQuery(this).attr('data-source-id'));
});
// order == ["id-0", "id-1", ...]
```

Then you can send them using ajax or add them to a hidden form field and re-order your array using PHP.

On the PHP-Side, you can use uksort:

```
$data = //my data
$order = ["id-0", "id-1", ...]
uksort($data, function($k1, $k2) use ($oder) {
  return array_search($k1, $order) - array_search($k2, $order);
});
```